# Sapui5 horizontal line

Tags: line, sapui5, horizontal-line

is there any alternative to the depricated"HorizontalDivider" in SAPUI5? Since Sap doesn´t mention any alternative, I ran over something like "" Element that draws a Horizontal line?

Answer (score 3):

It is better that you use a toolbar element as it has the bottom border. When you use the html `hr` tag, it does not respect the theme color while the toolbar use the theme color and also its spacing policy.

```
<sap.m.Toolbar width="100%" height="1px"/>
```

It the following picture you can see what is the result of using a toolbar with `1px` height.

[image: It shows how to use horizontal line in SAPUI5 by using toolbar]

And in the following picture the result of using html `hr` tag.

[image: Result of using hr tag in UI5 applications.]

Or you can use any boxing elements of the `UI5` and just play with its class. For example you can assign the class `sapMTBStandard` to your element to make a bottom border with suitable color in your theme.

Comment: That is cleaner than `<html:hr/>`

Comment: I prefer to use UI5 elements because of theme.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html:hr></html:hr>
```

Make sure you add `xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` library

Comment: you probably mean add the namespace?

Comment: yes indeed and correct me if i'm wrong , can't we say that as a library

Comment: Hi Santosh. A library incorporates functionality. In the context of XML a namespace creates a unique handle to an element - it acts more as a pointer / identifier.